# Submitting form via Ajax - FormData always empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I need to upload a photo on a server using ajax. I have set up the form the javascript as well, but the FormData object is always empty! I have tried various ways to reference the actual form, but still not working.

fiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/cjngvg8a/

Thanks!

html:

```
<form id="profileImageForm" action="update.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" value="hello" name="test" />
<input type="file" name="profile_pic" id="image_upload"/>
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

js:

```
$('#profileImageForm').on('submit',(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();     
    var formData = new FormData(this);

    console.log(formData);

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data:formData,
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(data){
            console.log("success");
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}));
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The data in a FormData object is not revealed by inspecting it with `console.log()`. It is there, you just can't see it.

If you examine the Net tab of your developer tools, you can see the form content is being uploaded.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You can use `Array.from(formData)` to see the values with a `console.log`

Comment: Do you have any idea why it isn't available in the console? Even `formData.entries` shows a length of 0.